# Windows phone Tile Images resolution/dimensions

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have published a Windows Phone 8 app recently and I've got a lot of complains about the quality of live tile image. 
I did test the app on the emulators and on Lumia 820 and didn't find anything.
Well, maybe it is something to do with Lumia 920.
So the question is what image width and height are being used in your Apps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your app built for wp7 or wp8?

Comment: The App was built for wp8.

Answer (score 1):

Would this [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on msdn help ?